# mouseover text gets misplaced after hovering multiple items

Tags: css, hover, styles, mouseover

Problem: The mouse over text description gets misplaced after the user has hovered over several items. It works initially, but then does not appear relative to where the cursor hovers.

**See Image below:**

[image: INFO TEXT MISPLACED]

Jsfiddle: [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Mauser/g3tfoa24/13/)

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".book-description").text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur")


});
```

```css
.book-item {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px;
}

.book-image {
  padding-right: 35px;
  float: left;
}

.book-thumbnail {
  height: 240px
}

.book-content {
  margin-left: 35px
}

.book-title {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  color: #313131;
}

.book-author {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: rgba(49, 49, 49, 0.5);
}

.book-description {
  /* overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 150px; */
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 18px;
  z-index: 999;
  display: none;
  background: lightyellow;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 18px;
  position: fixed;
}

.book-description-icon {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: italic;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  color: rgba(49, 49, 49, 0.5);
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.book-description-icon:hover+.book-description {
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  -webkit-animation: fadein 1s;
  /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
  -moz-animation: fadein 1s;
  /* Firefox < 16 */
  -ms-animation: fadein 1s;
  /* Internet Explorer */
  -o-animation: fadein 1s;
  /* Opera < 12.1 */
  animation: fadein 1s;
}

.book-icons {
  position: relative;
  top: 20%
}

.book-search input {
  width: 350px;
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="book-item"> <span class="book-image">
        <img class="book-thumbnail" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71T0PJT2F1L._SX316_BO1,204,203,200_.gif" />
      </span>
        <div class="book-content">
          <h3 class="book-title">{title}</h3>
          <p class="book-author">by {authors}</p>
          <span class="book-description-icon">{description}</span>
          <p class="book-description"></p>
          <span class="book-icons">{icons}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <div class="book-item"> <span class="book-image">
        <img class="book-thumbnail" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71T0PJT2F1L._SX316_BO1,204,203,200_.gif" />
      </span>
        <div class="book-content">
          <h3 class="book-title">{title}</h3>
          <p class="book-author">by {authors}</p>
          <span class="book-description-icon">{description}</span>
          <p class="book-description"></p>
          <span class="book-icons">{icons}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="book-item"> <span class="book-image">
        <img class="book-thumbnail" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71T0PJT2F1L._SX316_BO1,204,203,200_.gif" />
      </span>
        <div class="book-content">
          <h3 class="book-title">{title}</h3>
          <p class="book-author">by {authors}</p>
          <span class="book-description-icon">{description}</span>
          <p class="book-description"></p>
          <span class="book-icons">{icons}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="book-item"> <span class="book-image">
        <img class="book-thumbnail" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71T0PJT2F1L._SX316_BO1,204,203,200_.gif" />
      </span>
        <div class="book-content">
          <h3 class="book-title">{title}</h3>
          <p class="book-author">by {authors}</p>
          <span class="book-description-icon">{description}</span>
          <p class="book-description"></p>
          <span class="book-icons">{icons}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="book-item"> <span class="book-image">
        <img class="book-thumbnail" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71T0PJT2F1L._SX316_BO1,204,203,200_.gif" />
      </span>
        <div class="book-content">
          <h3 class="book-title">{title}</h3>
          <p class="book-author">by {authors}</p>
          <span class="book-description-icon">{description}</span>
          <p class="book-description"></p>
          <span class="book-icons">{icons}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <div class="book-item"> <span class="book-image">
        <img class="book-thumbnail" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71T0PJT2F1L._SX316_BO1,204,203,200_.gif" />
      </span>
        <div class="book-content">
          <h3 class="book-title">{title}</h3>
          <p class="book-author">by {authors}</p>
          <span class="book-description-icon">{description}</span>
          <p class="book-description"></p>
          <span class="book-icons">{icons}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="book-item"> <span class="book-image">
        <img class="book-thumbnail" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71T0PJT2F1L._SX316_BO1,204,203,200_.gif" />
      </span>
        <div class="book-content">
          <h3 class="book-title">{title}</h3>
          <p class="book-author">by {authors}</p>
          <span class="book-description-icon">{description}</span>
          <p class="book-description"></p>
          <span class="book-icons">{icons}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="book-item"> <span class="book-image">
        <img class="book-thumbnail" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71T0PJT2F1L._SX316_BO1,204,203,200_.gif" />
      </span>
        <div class="book-content">
          <h3 class="book-title">{title}</h3>
          <p class="book-author">by {authors}</p>
          <span class="book-description-icon">{description}</span>
          <p class="book-description"></p>
          <span class="book-icons">{icons}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

To replicate, hover over multiple items on the jsfiddle and you will see.

Comment: did my solution work for you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not on multiple hover, but on scrolling down.

Add `position: relative` to `book-content` and `position: absolute` on `book-description`

You have added position: fixed and absolute both on book-description, remove the position fixed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".book-description").text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur")


});
```

```css
.book-item {
  width: 500px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px;
}

.book-image {
  padding-right: 35px;
  float: left;
}

.book-thumbnail {
  height: 240px
}

.book-content {
  margin-left: 35px;
  position: relative;
}

.book-title {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-top: 6px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  color: #313131;
}

.book-author {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  letter-spacing: -1px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: rgba(49, 49, 49, 0.5);
}

.book-description {
  /* overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 150px; */
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 18px;
  z-index: 999;
  display: none;
  background: lightyellow;
  width: 200px;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.book-description-icon {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-style: italic;
  letter-spacing: 0px;
  color: rgba(49, 49, 49, 0.5);
  display: block;
  padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.book-description-icon:hover+.book-description {
  display: block;
  width: 500px;
  -webkit-animation: fadein 1s;
  /* Safari, Chrome and Opera > 12.1 */
  -moz-animation: fadein 1s;
  /* Firefox < 16 */
  -ms-animation: fadein 1s;
  /* Internet Explorer */
  -o-animation: fadein 1s;
  /* Opera < 12.1 */
  animation: fadein 1s;
}

.book-icons {
  position: relative;
  top: 20%
}

.book-search input {
  width: 350px;
  margin: 0
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="book-item"> <span class="book-image">
        <img class="book-thumbnail" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71T0PJT2F1L._SX316_BO1,204,203,200_.gif" />
      </span>
        <div class="book-content">
          <h3 class="book-title">{title}</h3>
          <p class="book-author">by {authors}</p>
          <span class="book-description-icon">{description}</span>
          <p class="book-description"></p>
          <span class="book-icons">{icons}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <div class="book-item"> <span class="book-image">
        <img class="book-thumbnail" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71T0PJT2F1L._SX316_BO1,204,203,200_.gif" />
      </span>
        <div class="book-content">
          <h3 class="book-title">{title}</h3>
          <p class="book-author">by {authors}</p>
          <span class="book-description-icon">{description}</span>
          <p class="book-description"></p>
          <span class="book-icons">{icons}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="book-item"> <span class="book-image">
        <img class="book-thumbnail" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71T0PJT2F1L._SX316_BO1,204,203,200_.gif" />
      </span>
        <div class="book-content">
          <h3 class="book-title">{title}</h3>
          <p class="book-author">by {authors}</p>
          <span class="book-description-icon">{description}</span>
          <p class="book-description"></p>
          <span class="book-icons">{icons}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="book-item"> <span class="book-image">
        <img class="book-thumbnail" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71T0PJT2F1L._SX316_BO1,204,203,200_.gif" />
      </span>
        <div class="book-content">
          <h3 class="book-title">{title}</h3>
          <p class="book-author">by {authors}</p>
          <span class="book-description-icon">{description}</span>
          <p class="book-description"></p>
          <span class="book-icons">{icons}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="book-item"> <span class="book-image">
        <img class="book-thumbnail" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71T0PJT2F1L._SX316_BO1,204,203,200_.gif" />
      </span>
        <div class="book-content">
          <h3 class="book-title">{title}</h3>
          <p class="book-author">by {authors}</p>
          <span class="book-description-icon">{description}</span>
          <p class="book-description"></p>
          <span class="book-icons">{icons}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col">
      <div class="book-item"> <span class="book-image">
        <img class="book-thumbnail" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71T0PJT2F1L._SX316_BO1,204,203,200_.gif" />
      </span>
        <div class="book-content">
          <h3 class="book-title">{title}</h3>
          <p class="book-author">by {authors}</p>
          <span class="book-description-icon">{description}</span>
          <p class="book-description"></p>
          <span class="book-icons">{icons}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="book-item"> <span class="book-image">
        <img class="book-thumbnail" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71T0PJT2F1L._SX316_BO1,204,203,200_.gif" />
      </span>
        <div class="book-content">
          <h3 class="book-title">{title}</h3>
          <p class="book-author">by {authors}</p>
          <span class="book-description-icon">{description}</span>
          <p class="book-description"></p>
          <span class="book-icons">{icons}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="book-item"> <span class="book-image">
        <img class="book-thumbnail" src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71T0PJT2F1L._SX316_BO1,204,203,200_.gif" />
      </span>
        <div class="book-content">
          <h3 class="book-title">{title}</h3>
          <p class="book-author">by {authors}</p>
          <span class="book-description-icon">{description}</span>
          <p class="book-description"></p>
          <span class="book-icons">{icons}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Updated[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g3tfoa24/16/)